# Unity game randomly closes when phone is streaming the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Unity android game (frequently) randomly closes on some phones when it's streaming with the [YouTube Gaming App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.gaming) for example. I have Unity version 5.3.5f1. I have to say that this phenomenon did not happen in the past when streaming, it's new... What could be the source of this problem?

I have tried downgrading my Unity software to a previous version but that didn't change anything.

As you can see in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/xTRh3Bumj-4?t=22m5s) (start at 22:05), the game closes many times. This video is not mine, I've asked a person to stream my game for testing purposes...

Comment: most probably you are running out of RAM. You should be getting low memory warnings on your device, check logcat.